# Editable Combobox are frozen to edit after selected

Tags: c#, wpf

I have in wpf control editable combobox.

```
<ComboBox Width="200"  Name="quickSearchText"
    TextBoxBase.TextChanged="searchTextChanged"
    IsTextSearchEnabled="False" 
    StaysOpenOnEdit="True" IsEditable="True">
</ComboBox>
```

After text typing I'm changing the Combobox Items (Like Autocompleted textbox).

```
private void searchTextChanged(object sender, TextChangedEventArgs e)
{
    string text = quickSearchText.Text; //Get typing text.
    List<string> autoList = new List<string>();

    autoList.AddRange(suggestions.Where(suggestion => !string.IsNullOrEmpty(text)&& suggestion.StartsWith(text))); //Get possible suggestions.

   // Show all, if text is empty.
   if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(text) && autoList.Count == 0)
   {
       autoList.AddRange(suggestions);
   }

   quickSearchText.ItemsSource = autoList;
   quickSearchText.IsDropDownOpen = autoList.Count != 0; //Open if any.
}
```

If I select an item from dropdown or type text and press `Enter` the TextboxBase froze and I can't edit it. (But can highlight the text and open/close the dropdown)

How to fix it?

Comment: You can use `TextBox` Control & `Popup Control with Combobox`. On `TextChanged` event of TextBox you can Show/Hide `Popup`.

Comment: @Amol Bavannavar thanks.
it is one of the solutions. But why the current solution does not work?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The current Solution doesn't work because of this line:

```
quickSearchText.ItemsSource = autoList;
```

This will reset your `ComboBox` data and thus every changes made in input text will be lost.

for your solution to work you should use *data binding* like the following :

Code behind:

```
public MainWindow()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    DataContext = this;
    autoList = new ObservableCollection<string>();
}

private List<string> suggestions;
public ObservableCollection<string> autoList { get; set; }
private void searchTextChanged(object sender, TextChangedEventArgs e)
{
    string text = quickSearchText.Text; //Get typing text.

    var suggestedList = suggestions.Where(suggestion => !string.IsNullOrEmpty(text) && suggestion.StartsWith(text)); //Get possible suggestions
    autoList.Clear();

    foreach (var item in suggestedList)
    {
        autoList.Add(item);
    }

    // Show all, if text is empty.
    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(text) && autoList.Count == 0)
    {
        foreach (var item in suggestions)
        {
            autoList.Add(item);
        }
    }

    quickSearchText.IsDropDownOpen = autoList.Count != 0; //Open if any.
}
```

Xaml:

```
<ComboBox Width="200"  Name="quickSearchText"
            ItemsSource="{Binding autoList}"
            TextBoxBase.TextChanged="searchTextChanged"
            IsTextSearchEnabled="False" 
            StaysOpenOnEdit="True" IsEditable="True">
</ComboBox>
```

Comment: The use ObservableCollection has helped me, but the binded data have not been updated on the View, so I still have to reset the ItemsSource by code.

Answer (score 1):

Put in:

```
quickSearchText.ItemsSource = null;
```

as the first line in the searchTextChanged function. It seems not clearing the ItemsSource beforehand causes strange behavior and putting this line first seems to fix it.

Answer (score 0):

Add this in your searchTextChanged method to enable editing again.

```
quickSearchText.SelectedIndex = -1;
```